# Common entry point for method calls in WCF stub

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-client, wcfserviceclient

I've been looking into migrating our application to use a service reference instead of a web reference.
However, I can't find an equivalent for SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke()

In our application, we've overridden this method so that some additional code executes before and after each web method call such as refreshing client credentials, exception processing and trey, etc.

Does anyone know if there's an equivalent for the abovementioned interface? Or is there an alternative approach for our needs?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WCF offers extension points on different levels in the stack:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stdeepdive/2012/05/07/wcf-extension-points-and-how-to-use-them/

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it. Much appreciated.